# Bash Script - Checking a String Which Has Curly Braces

Tags: bash

I have the following portion of a script which is adding a tenant via a curl command and then checking the response. 
The response is `{ "tenant": "provisioned" }`

Here is my script:

```
printf "\n** ADDING A TENANT **\n"
TenantResponse=`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'serviceSharedSecret: sharedsecret' -d '{
"settings": {},
"longName": "QA Test Server",
"tenant_id": "2",
"long_name": "QA Test Server",
"mwa": "string",
"env_overrides": {},
"rough_sizing": "string"
}' "http://${IP_ADDRESS}:8080/rest/1.0/dg/tenants"`
if [[ $TenantResponse == '{ "tenant": "provisioned" }' ]]
  then
    echo "Tenant 2 was added"
    echo '<testcase classname="TenantProvisioning" name="Provision_Tenant_2"/>' >> isoValidationReport.xml
else

    echo "There is a problem provisioning tenant: $TenantResponse"
    echo '<testcase classname="TenantProvisioning" name="Provision_Tenant_2">' >> isoValidationReport.xml
    echo '<failure message="There is a problem provisioning tenant" type="failure"/>' >> isoValidationReport.xml
    echo '</testcase>' >> isoValidationReport.xml
    error_count=$((error_count + 1))
fi
```

I have tried my `[[ $TenantResponse == '{ "tenant": "provisioned" }' ]]` with double quotes around the curly braces, single quotes as you can see above as well as no quotes. Seems like nothing is working.

Comment: Does enclosing `$TenantResponse` in double quotes solve the problem? If not, you should say how it is not working : is an error raised, or does the condition just fail when you expect it to succeed?

Comment: It returns the error in the else clause with the tenant response `{ "tenant" : "provisioned" }`

Comment: Try to write content of the `$TenantResponse` to the temporal file and then explore carefully.

Comment: Also, probably you want to use `[ $TenantResponse == '{ "tenant": "provisioned" }' ]` (with single squared brackets) since this is actually the right way to use `test` command. Type `man test` to ensure.

Comment: I proposed to save content to the file to ensure that it is actually `{ "tenant": "provisioned" }` with no spaces and new line characters around.

Comment: The response may actually end with a `\r\n` pair, and the command substitution only strips the `\n`, leaving the `\r`. This causes your string comparison to fail.

Comment: The error message is actually printing out the response. It is indeed `{ "tenant": "provisioned" }` Also I checked the response in Postman and this is indeed the response. No special characters that I can see.

Comment: Look at the file with `cat -A`, otherwise, you'd miss a stray `\r`.

Comment: @DarthOpto, `echo` could hide some spaces/line feeds from you eyes. Try to run `echo -n '{ "tenant": "provisioned" }' | md5sum` (you will have 45964905a1b4dea1240b5c79217b94c5). Then, try to get md5 of the string you've got and ensure md5 hashes equal.

Comment: Curly braces don't in any way break, mess up, or interfere with string comparisons in bash. You've got something else going on.

Comment: Use `printf '%q\n' "$TenantResponse" '{ "tenant": "provisioned" }'`, and compare the two lines of output from that command (even better, edit them into the question!). If your comparison returns false, the output of `printf %q` -- rendering the variable contents in an `eval`-safe, human-readable manner -- will differ in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments suggest, this is most likely due to a carriage return or possibly a trailing space. That's how fragile this approach is.

The string with curly braces is actually JSON, and should be treated as such:

```
if [[ $(jq '.tenant == "provisioned"' <<< "$TenantResponse") == "true" ]]
then
  echo "the 'tenant' field has the value 'provisioned'"
else
  echo "it doesn't"
fi
```

This would make it robust against formatting and future proof it against changes:

```
{ "tenant": "provisioned" }
{"tenant":"provisioned"}
{"tenant":"provisioned", "year": "2016"}
{"tenant":"unavailable", "previous": "provisioned"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `curl` output through `tr -dc '[:print:]'`. This will remove any non-printable characters, including `\r`. This will also remove `\n`, but you might not care about that do to the check.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my if statement to look for the word `provisioned` in the response. Like this `if [[ $TenantResponse == *"provisioned"* ]]`

This worked.

Comment: If what you want is to make a semantic decision based on interpreting something as JSON, using `jq` (or another tool that can actually parse JSON) is probably the ideal choice. `*provisioned*` will also match `unprovisioned`, or `{ "tenant": "foo", "comment": "unprovisioned" }`, etc.

Comment: I claim `[[ $TenantResponse == '{ "tenant": "provisionsed" }'? ]]` would work as well, if the only problem is the trailing `\r`.

Comment: @chepner, agreed, but I'd use `TenantResponse=${TenantResponse%$'\r'}` to strip that prior to the comparison, if we're confident it's our problem, rather than using a `?` single-character wildcard (which will break if the output ever *doesn't* contain a trailing character).